# Azure Web App Wordpress how to add Virtual Directory?

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Wordpress app is running fine at "/". I used the Kudu console to add a new filesystem folder, placed a hello.txt file in it, and then used the Path Mapping setting in the Azure portal to create a virtual directory to match.

I then navigated to the virtual dir in another web browser session, but Wordpress appears to be controlling the pathing because it gave the "not found" page.

How can I control the routes when I add another virtual dir to the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is my test to set the virtual directory.

1. Create the 'test' folder under 'site' folder in the KUDU, and put the 'test.txt' file in the folder.

[image]

2. Set the '/test' virtual path with `site\test` path.

   [image]
3. Save the settings and restart the web, view the text file with the url `https://your web name.azurewebsites.net/test/test.txt`.

[image]